# Pytest alternative to --verbose --verbose (-v -v)

Tags: pytest

Is there a single argument alternative to the double verbose options for pytest runs? It's a little deceptive looking seeming like a merge error or a benign redundant typo when it shows up in shell script source.

I'm not sure the evolution of the verbosity inputs, but its showing up in our repo from tips like the following that pytest gives upon failures.

```
...Full output truncated (19 lines hidden), use '-vv' to show
```

Would be nice if there was something like `--verbose2` or something of the sort.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out there is such an option, it's under `verbosity`.

`--verbosity=VERBOSE`

and tracing around the [codebase](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/af2b0e117459b7f41c845f9f676e904d3b35e5a2/testing/python/collect.py#L79) seems to imply that `0,1,2` are valid values. There doesn't appear to be any documentation on that point however.

Looking at the command argument [definition](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/6c2d35891879408ccd1ca0d05355d3baa046f9da/src/_pytest/terminal.py#L80-L88) I can also see the behavior and pattern they're utilizing, which is the `count` action which sheds new light on redundant arguments; I didn't even realize that was a pattern.

```py
group._addoption(
    "-v",
    "--verbose",
    action="count",
    default=0,
    dest="verbose",
    help="increase verbosity.",
)
```

So it would seem that

```py
"-vv" === "--verbose --verbose" === "--verbosity=2"
```